# UIButton function will not respond when called in a UITableView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, uibutton

I have a `UITableView` and I have also defined a subclass of it to include a button in each of my cells.
In order to check that its functionality works properly I have defined an `@objc` function (since I am doing it programmatically).

I can see the tables cells are present as well as the button visible inside it as I already registered it in the `viewDidLoad` function of my `UIViewController` class, but when I click it it does not respond. I am expecting to get a message printed in the console

```
 @objc func actbuttonFuncCall(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("button clicked")
    }
```

This how I defined the `tableView` function for the `cellForRowAt` section:

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UITableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell

           if let model = viewsArray[indexPath.row] {
               // name  assinged from another VC
                   cell.textLabel?.text = model.name
               cell.textLabel?.textColor = .systemPink
               
               cell.button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
               cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
               cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(actbuttonFuncCall), for: .touchUpInside)

               }
         
           return cell
       }
```

And this is the subclass for my `UIButton`

```
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    let button = UIButton()
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        button.setTitle("Get to it", for: .normal)
                button.backgroundColor = .blue
        addSubview(button)
        
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
               NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                   button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
                   button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
                   button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100), // Adjust as needed
                   button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)  // Adjust as needed
               ])
      
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I there any other action I should perform to make my button functionality work?

Comment: 1. The button should be added to the cell's `contentView`, not directly to the cell. 2. Use Xcode's "view hierarchy" debugger and make sure the button is not being clipped by any of its parent views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @HangaRash said on their comment, you should add button in cell's contentView, it will be:

```swift
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    ...
    //addSubview(button)
    contentView.addSubview(button)
}
```

This is different from view hierarchy:

1. addSubview(button)

```
UITableView
     |---MyCustomCell
             |--- UIButton (Get to it)
             |--- UITableViewCellContentView

//The button is below UITableViewCellContentView so the cell 
//will receive touch event from `didSelectRowAt` delegate.
```

2. contentView.addSubview(button)

```
UITableView
     |---MyCustomCell
             |--- UITableViewCellContentView
                              |--- UIButton (Get to it)

//The button is above UITableViewCellContentView so the cell 
//will receive touch event from UIButton's first if within its frame.
//And receives `didSelectRowAt` delegate if out of button frame.
```

Comment: Note that the constraints should probably be updated too.

Answer (score 0):

**You can achieve this by using protocol and delegate method.**

**Click on this link for detailed answer =>** [How to UITableView Click image and title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74451248/how-to-uitableview-click-image-and-title/74456383#74456383)